# Custom Ord instance hangs on lists

Tags: haskell, typeclass

```
import Data.Function (on)
import Data.List (sort)

data Monomial = Monomial 
    { m_coeff :: Coefficient 
    , m_powers :: [(Variable, Power)]
    }
    deriving ()

instance Ord Monomial where
    (>=) = on (>=) m_powers

instance Eq Monomial where
    (==) = on (==) m_powers
```

That's an excerpt from my code, cut down to principal size. Let's try comparing:

```
*Main> (Monomial 1 [("x",2)]) > (Monomial (-1) [])
/* Computation hangs here */
*Main> (Monomial 1 [("x",2)]) < (Monomial (-1) [])
/* Computation hangs here */
```

On a side note, it's interesting that if I replace `s/(>=)/(>)/g` in instance declaration, it will not hang on the fist pair, but still will on the second:

```
*Main> (Monomial 1 [("x",2)]) > (Monomial (-1) [])
True
*Main> (Monomial 1 [("x",2)]) < (Monomial (-1) [])
/* Computation hangs here */
```

Although the standard states minimal declaration of `Eq instance` to be either`$compare$` or `$(>=)$`.

What might be the problem here? (>=) on lists seems to work just fine.

Comment: `type Variable = String`, right? What happens if you define `compare` instead of `(>=)`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Short answer:**
You need to provide either `(<=)` or `compare` to have a complete definition for `Ord`, not `(>=)`.

**Longer explanation:**
It is common for type classes in Haskell to have default implementations of some methods implemented in terms of other methods. You can then choose which ones you want to implement. For example, `Eq` looks like this:

```
class Eq a where
  (==), (/=) :: a -> a -> Bool

  x /= y = not (x == y)
  x == y = not (x /= y)
```

Here, you must either implement `(==)` or `(/=)`, otherwise trying to use either of them will cause an infinite loop. Which methods you need to provide is usually listed as the *minimal complete definition* in the documentation.

The minimal complete definition for `Ord` instances, [as listed in the documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#t%3aOrd), is either `(<=)` or `compare`. Since you've only provided `(>=)`, you have not provided a complete definition, and therefore some of the methods will loop. You can fix it by e.g. changing your instance to provide `compare` instead.

```
instance Ord Monomial where
  compare = compare `on` m_powers
```

Comment: There's an `instance Eq Monomial` just below the `instance Ord Monomial`, and I defined (==) there.

Comment: @FrancisDrake: Yes, I just used `Eq` as an example since it's simpler. Read the rest of my answer.

Comment: You've nailed it, but it's hidden between a lot of unnecessary fluff. The answer is simply "The minimal complete definition for Ord is `<=`, not `>=`". I don't think such a large lecture on the meaning of "minimal complete definition" is called for.

Answer (score 6):

Let's look at the default instance for `Ord`:

```
class  (Eq a) => Ord a  where 
    compare              :: a -> a -> Ordering
    (<), (<=), (>), (>=) :: a -> a -> Bool
    max, min             :: a -> a -> a

    compare x y = if x == y then EQ
                  -- NB: must be '<=' not '<' to validate the
                  -- above claim about the minimal things that
                  -- can be defined for an instance of Ord:
                  else if x <= y then LT
                  else GT

    x <  y = case compare x y of { LT -> True;  _ -> False }
    x <= y = case compare x y of { GT -> False; _ -> True }
    x >  y = case compare x y of { GT -> True;  _ -> False }
    x >= y = case compare x y of { LT -> False; _ -> True }

        -- These two default methods use '<=' rather than 'compare'
        -- because the latter is often more expensive
    max x y = if x <= y then y else x
    min x y = if x <= y then x else y
```

So, if you supply `>=` and `==` as above, only, then you are in trouble, since:

- `>` is defined in terms of `compare`

**But**

- `compare` is defined in terms of `<=`
- `<=` is defined in terms of `compare`

So you have an infinite loop!

A minimum definition must defined `<=` or `compare`, not '>=`.